# TypeScript determine type click handler will return

Tags: typescript, promise, onclick

I have a custom button control who's click handler can return a promise or void as below:

```
// --- Options for button control
export interface buttonOptions {
   aProperty: string
   anotherProperty: number
   onClick: Promise<IButtonClickResult> | void
}

// --- Click handler added for click event inside control class
protected clickHandler(): Promise<IButtonClickResult> | void {
   if(returnsPromise) displaySpinner()

   various operations

   this.options.onClick(this)
}
```

The control is created using the builder pattern so it would be created as such:

```
buttonClass.build()
  .options({
      aProperty: 'Hope this works',
      anotherProperty: 1,
      onClick: () => {
          return new Promise<IButtonClickResult>((resolve, reject) => {         

            // --- I suppose I could pass reference to resolve or reject to async function and allow that function to resolve or reject the promise
            asyncOperation(resolve, reject)                         
          }).then((result) => button.onClickSuccess(result)).catch((error) => button.onclickError(error))
```

onClick could also be assigned a function that returns void as:

```
console.log('I was clicked')
```

If the click handler returns a promise, I want to add a spinner to the button until the promise resolves or rejects, then I will replace the spinner with the original button content through .then or maybe an oops through .catch

My question is how to determine if a promise will be returned inside the button's click handler so I will know whether or not to display a spinner on the button.

Any help is greatly appreciated. I have attempted typeof and instanceof, but to no avail. Potentially I was not using them correctly? My apologies, I am fairly new to TypeScript and NodeJS.

Comment: I'm a bit confused. What does `someOperation` return? A promise, or something else? Also the `onClick` method as written can *only* return `void` right now. Under what circumstances should it be returning a `Promise` instead? Finally, can you show us what you tried using `instanceof`? Might help us get a better idea of what you're trying to accomplish in this example.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I've been confused myself. Just recently started working with promises a few days ago. I will update the question in an attempt to clarify

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're dealing with a union type you can simply test your way out of the `void` branch (assuming that you have `strictNullChecks` turned on):

```
const result: Promise<IButtonClickResult> | void = this.onClick(...args);
if (result === undefined) {
  // Nothing returned, don't do the async thing
} else {
  // result is of type Promise here and Typescript will let you call .then, etc.
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, that makes perfect sense. It's a whole new world I'm stepping into. Been some growing pains, but loving it.